# ajaxStart() "$ is not defined"

Tags: jquery

```
<script src="js/jquery/jquery-1.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

how can I setup ajaxStart??

I get "$.ajaxStart is not a function"

```
function Loader(){
    this.loader = null;

    this.cnstr = function(){
        if(!this.loader){
            this.loader = DOM.div(document.body);
            with(this.loader){
                className = 'loader';
                innerHTML = 'loader';
                style.display = 'none';
            }

            elm_position_center(this.loader);
            $(this.loader).fadeIn(1000);
        }
    };

    this.dstr = function(){
        if(this.loader){
            DOM.rmv(this.loader);
        }
    };
}
var Loader = new Loader();

$.ajaxStart(function(){
    Loader.cnstr();
});

$.ajaxStop(function(){
    Loader.dstr();
});
```

EDIT:

$.ajaxStart is not a function

```
window.onload = function(){
    $.ajaxStart(function(){
        Loader.cnstr();
    });

    $.ajaxStop(function(){
        Loader.dstr();
    });
};
```

Comment: you do not have jQuery loaded, or it is in conflict with some other library.

Comment: Please also add the script declaration for the files that you have included in the page for `JQuery` and the script tag declaration in which the above code exists.

Comment: is there any other js library u r using?? like `mootools`, `prototype`

Comment: no... only jquery... if I escape the lines with ajaxStart/Stop everything else with $ works

Comment: if I put the code in a window.onload function I still get "$.ajaxStart is not a function"

Comment: I assume that ajaxStart() and ajaxStop() are built-in functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jquery file is probably missing or you didn't load it correctly

Comment: now its loaded before this code, but now I get "$.ajaxStart is not a function"

Answer (score 9):

this works..

```
$(document).ajaxStart();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that jQuery is loaded. Try adding this to your document:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: even if I put the function in a window.onload function

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#loadingAnimation").bind({
   ajaxStart: function(){ $(this).show(); },
   ajaxStop: function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Essentially binding your loadingAnimationElement to the globally fired ajaxStart and ajaxStop events. Only shows up when you intend it to.

When jQuery is not performing any Ajax requests and a new request is initiated, it fires an ajaxStart event. If other requests begin before this first one ends, those new requests do not cause a new ajaxStart event. The ajaxStop event is triggered when the last pending Ajax request is completed and jQuery is no longer performing any network activity.

//Thanks Kevin Brown for reminding me to explain the example.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since jQuery 3.5.0 aliases like `ajaxStart` are deprecated.

> We’ve also put AJAX event aliases on the list, they can be replaced by `.on('ajaxStart', …)` and the like. jQuery Migrate will warn about these now-deprecated methods, but they’ll stick around until jQuery 4.0.

http://blog.jquery.com/2020/04/10/jquery-3-5-0-released/